# Error installing RQDA: unable to access index for repository NA/src/contrib:

Tags: r, installation, rqda

I've downloaded GTK+ and installed it.

When I run `install.packages(c('blob','RSQLite','RQDA'))`,
or `install.packages("RQDA",dependencies=c("Depends", "Imports"))`

I get this same error:

> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> NA/src/contrib:   scheme not supported in URL
> 'NA/src/contrib/PACKAGES' Warning in install.packages :   packages
> ‘blob’, ‘RSQLite’, ‘RQDA’ are not available (for R version 3.6.3)
> Warning in install.packages :   unable to access index for repository
> NA/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:   scheme not supported in URL
> 'NA/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'

What's the problem and what can I do?

Comment: The package is no longer on CRAN: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQDA/index.html

Comment: Do you know where it is now?

Comment: You can go the CRAN archive and download the latest version, then install it locally. https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/RQDA/

Answer (score 2):

RQDA cannot be installed directly since R 3.6, I understand. However, @[BroVic](https://twitter.com/BroVic) developed an R package to install all the necessary dependencies (some not a part of R) called [RQDAassist](https://github.com/BroVic/RQDAassist). I'm on Windows 10 and running R 4.1 and this worked for me:

`# install.packages("devtools")`

`devtools::install_github("BroVic/RQDAassist")`

`RQDAassist::install()`

Then you can simply launch RQDA from the console or in a md file

`library(RQDA)`

Comment: Bizarre. Out of curiosity, wouldn’t it have been easier to fork and fix the RQDA package, rather than write a separate helper package?

Comment: @KonradRudolph such a fork exists. The reason I wrote a script (and then a package) was to install that specific last (pre-archive) CRAN version of RQDA that my own team uses. Also, the RQDAassist package has other helper functions for working with RQDA.

Comment: @BroVic Thanks, good to know. And thanks for making the package available for others.

Comment: Thanks for the support!